# Compare two columns in Data frame python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 excel files as input .

```
F1
FileName        Name   Gender
4-F_994637.txt  XXX    Not Identified
4-F_994576.txt  XXX    Not Identified
3-F_977039.txt  XXX    Not Identified
4-F_992516.txt  XXX    Not Identified
3-F_980311.txt  XXX    Not Identified
4-F_994638.txt  XXX    Female
4-F_994126.txt  XXX    Female
3-F_677039.txt  XXX    female
4-F_322516.txt  XXX    male
3-F_677311.txt  XXX    male

F2
FileName        Name   Gender
4-F_994637.txt  XXX    Male
4-F_994576.txt  XXX    Male
3-F_977039.txt  XXX    Male
4-F_992516.txt  XXX    Male
3-F_980311.txt  XXX    Male
```

All I want is first i need to select **"Gender = 'Non Identified'"** and compare F1 and F2 with column **"FileName"** . And if there is match I should replace the Gender in F1  with **Male**

I tried the below code , but getting error

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_excel('F1.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('F2.xlsx')

pick=df1[df1["Gender"]=='Not Identified']
filecompare=pick["FileName"] == df2["FileName"]

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Can someone Help what is this error all about.

Thanks,
Meera

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

With pandas version 1.1.1, your code block

```py
pick=df1[df1["Gender"]=='Not Identified']
filecompare = pick["FileName"] == df2["FileName"]
display(filecompare)
```

returns

[image: output_for_question]

You can check for the similar Filenames with the `isin()` method and set them to 'male' with `.loc`.

```py
cond_male = (df1['Gender']=='Not Identified') & (df1['FileName'].isin(df2['FileName']))
df1.loc[cond_male,'Gender']='Male'
```

returns

[image: output_question]